# Cyborg M.M.O.7 Mouse Extra Buttons - No 11-mouse.conf

Tags: 12.10, xorg, mouse, button

I have a Cyborg M.M.O.7 mouse with quite a few extra buttons, and I'd like to be able to bind them to things. I've found a [post here](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/481201-madcatz-r-t-7-mmo-gaming-mouse-issue.html) that seems to detail the process, but when I attempted to carry out the steps I noticed that there is no "etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-mouse.conf" file. I discovered that apparently later versions of Ubuntu use "usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d" but there is still no 11-mouse.conf file.

```
# dir /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
10-evdev.conf         50-synaptics.conf  51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf      50-vmmouse.conf
11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-wacom.conf
```

Can I simply create this file? Will the steps stated in the post work?

Thanks,
YM

Answer (score 1):

> Can I simply create this file?

Yes.
 As a general rule, when a config file is mentioned and it is found missing on the system you try to edit, there's 4 possibilities:

1. The system you are trying to edit was replaced by another one, e.g. RC files -> systemd
2. The structure changed with an update
3. The file is superseeded elsewhere e.g. Xorg.conf and xorg.conf.d/stuff.conf
4. The file is only required if you change the default configuration e.g. system/default = `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, configured = `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

As for what to put in it, this should work:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Mouse Remap"
MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg M.M.O.7 Gaming Mouse"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 9 10 11 12 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

[source](http://www.overclock.net/t/826113/the-official-cyborg-r-a-t-and-m-m-o-owners-club/0_40)

EDIT:
I tested it with at least Gentoo (I was going to do some compiler flags testing with a new CPU and I remembered to test the mouse) and it works fine. I suppose that it works with pretty much any Linux-based Distribution.

I hope it helps you understand!